# Goal "for" or Goal "of"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> The goal **for** these negotiations is to reach a mutually-agreed long-term comprehensive solution that would ensure Iranˈs nuclear program will be exclusively peaceful.

while we have a noun phrase "the goal" connected to another noun phrase "these negotiations", why isn't *of* used instead of *for*?

Comment: Short answer: in my American dialect, either works.  "Goal for" is a commonly used phrase, as in "The goal for 2014 is to get 5 new clients"

Comment: @swbarnes2 I think there is a subtle distinction. In your example "for" works, but it doesn't always. "Of" is a safer choice. I addressed the distinction (poorly, I'm afraid) in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The use of "for" vs "of" in that example is hard to explain, and I think it's more of a question of style than correctness. It doesn't feel right say that any one thing is *the* goal, or even *a* goal "for" a person. That somehow says that the person is less important than the goal, whatever that goal may be. However, in your example you quote the goal "for" an activity. That works; the goal is the entire purpose of the activity. "Of" would work there too.

I'd like to point out something else about the phrase. To refer something as *the* goal of something or someone, that goal needs to be the primary purpose.

For instance, it is *the* goal of a teacher for the students to learn the material. However, it is *a* goal of Mrs. Brown (the teacher) for her students to learn. In other words, Mrs. Brown has other priorities too, she's not *just* a teacher. Perhaps she's a wife, mother and Scrabble player too. So the big difference here isn't the use of "for" vs "of", the important distinction is between "a" or "the".

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, *goal for* suggests a third party stating (or predicting?) the goal. If *goal of* is used instead, it might would have suggest the authentic/declared goal.

For examples -

> The *goal for* you is to pass with high grades in this examination - Maybe, the parents have predicted (or set) goal for their kid. **On the other hand...** 
>   The *goal of* him is to pass with high grades in this examination - It's pretty confirmed from a pupil's side!

Comment: I don't like "goal of *him*" that doesn't sound right.

Comment: Agree with Jolenealaska. I think "goal of his" is grammatically right but of course "his goal" is much more natural.